# Simple Cursor Adapter Throw Exception illegal Argument exception?

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, simplecursoradapter

My Cursor

```
    Cursor c= db.query(DBHelper.EXAM_DATA,new String [] {DBHelper.EXAM,DBHelper.FILE}, null,null, null, null, null);
```

Loop for the Cursor

```
c.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        name = c.getString(0);
        file = c.getString(1);
        Toast.makeText(this, name + "   "+file  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_reasoning, c, new String [] {file}, new int [] {R.id.txtList});
        LvReasoning.setAdapter(adapter);
    }while(c.moveToNext());
```

Logcat Showing This Error

```
01-20 16:33:55.154: E/AndroidRuntime(2426): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-20 16:33:55.154: E/AndroidRuntime(2426): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.xmlparsing/com.androidhive.xmlparsing.ListReasoning}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
```

My Table have _id Column but I do not know how to solve this error

Comment: what is column 1 in your table?

Comment: but you have `name = c.getString(0);` i guess column in index based so 0 is id right?

Comment: then look at the constructor of adapter and have the right params for the same. Also there is no need to set adapter everytime in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c.moveToFirst();
    do
    {
        name = c.getString(0);
        file = c.getString(1);
        Toast.makeText(this, name + "   "+file  ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_reasoning, c, new String [] {DBHelper.FILE}, new int [] {R.id.txtList});

    }while(c.moveToNext());
    LvReasoning.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I used this and This is Working. I have passed DBHelper table field name and its Work Fine.. But I really dont know Why that code not worked...

Answer (score 0):

The cursor given to a SimpleCursorAdapter must contain a column named _id. The fact that it exists in the table is not enough, you have to select it so include it in the list of columns returned:

```
Cursor c= db.query(DBHelper.EXAM_DATA,new String [] {"_id", DBHelper.EXAM, DBHelper.FILE}, null,null, null, null, null);
```

You also only need to instantiate and set the adapter once. Move these statements outside of the while loop (you can remove the loop entirely if you don't need to toast the contents of each cursor row):

```
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_reasoning, c, new String [] {file}, new int [] {R.id.txtList});
LvReasoning.setAdapter(adapter);
```

For each cursor row, the adapter will then map the value of column 'file' to R.id.txtList within R.layout.row_reasoning.